# Combinatoric Proof of $i(n+1,k) = i(n,k) + i(n, k-1) + i(n, k-2) + i(n, k-2) + \cdot\cdot\cdot + i(n, k-n) $

Tags: combinatorics

Let $i(n,k)$ denote the number of permutations where $\sigma \in S_n$ with $i(\sigma) = k$, that is $k$ inversions.

I want to provide combinatoric proof for the below statement:

$i(n+1,k) = i(n,k) + i(n, k-1) + i(n, k-2) + i(n, k-2) + \cdot\cdot\cdot + i(n, k-n) $

---

To prove this, since the RHS denotes for the disjoint number of permutations at each terms, I want to well-dissect the LHS into $n+1$ disjoint cases.

I can easily think that $i(n,k)$ from LHS corresponds to the case of $i(n+1, k)$ where the n+1 always positioned at the last of the permutation.

However, from the second term of LHS, can't figure out to where should it be corresponded to.

---

Any hint/advice to approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Take a permutation $\sigma\in S_{n+1}$ with $i(\sigma) = k$ and assume that $\sigma(j)=n+1$ with $1\leq j\leq n+1$. If we "eliminate" $n+1$ and shift to the left the entries we obtain a permutation $\sigma'\in S_{n}$. What is $i(\sigma') $?

P.S. By the way the above identity follows also from the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)
$$F(z) =\sum_{k=0}^{\binom{n}{2}} i(n,k)z^k= \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (1+z+z^2+\cdots +z^j).$$

Comment: got it. but I don't know the concept of generating function yet. will check it! thx again